# jQuery: Loaded HTML is invisible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently try to load HTML code into a div using jQuery and this code:

```
<script language="javascript">
   $(function(){
      $(".loadmain").click(function(){
         $("#main-content").load("startjourney2.html");
      });
   });
</script>
```

I have got my button here:

```
<a class="loadmain">Play</a>
```

And my div below

```
<div id="main-content" class="abs dark-template">
```

And last but not least the code in the startjourney2.html

```
<div class="page-wrapper">

    <!--Page sidebar-->
    <div class="page-side">
        <div class="inner-wrapper vcenter-wrapper">
            <div class="side-content vcenter">
                <div class="title">
                    <span class="second-part">Start your</span>
                    <span>Journey</span>
                </div>
                <p>Some text goes here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/Page sidebar-->

    <!--Page main content-->
    <div class="page-main">
        <!-- services wrapper -->
        <div class="vertical-folio">

            <!-- services Item -->
            <div class="vf-item tj-hover-3 set-bg inview-animate inview-fadeleft">

                <img src="assets/img/portfolio/horizontal/city1.jpg" alt="alt" class="img-responsive">

                <!-- Item Overlay -->
                <div class="tj-overlay vcenter-wrapper">
                    <div class="overlay-texts vcenter">
                        <h3 class="title">Tracing Lines</h3>
                        <h4 class="subtitle">11 % - Last played: 27/08/2014 @ 11:59 p.m.</h4>
                        <br/>
                        <a href="startjourney.html#" class="btn btn-transparent">Continue Journey</a>
                        <a href="startjourney.html#" class="btn btn-toranj alt">Quit Journey</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /Item Overlay -->

            </div>
            <!-- /services Item -->

            <!-- services Item -->
            <div class="vf-item tj-hover-3 set-bg inview-animate inview-fadeleft">

                <img src="assets/img/portfolio/horizontal/city2.jpg" alt="alt" class="img-responsive">
                <!-- Item Overlay -->
                <div class="tj-overlay vcenter-wrapper">
                    <div class="overlay-texts vcenter">
                        <h3 class="title">Reveal</h3>
                        <h4 class="subtitle">97 % - Last played: 12/11/2014 @ 07:54 a.m.</h4>
                        <br/>
                        <a href="startjourney.html#" class="btn btn-transparent">Continue Journey</a>
                        <a href="startjourney.html#" class="btn btn-toranj alt">Quit Journey</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /Item Overlay -->

            </div>
            <!-- /services Item -->

            <!-- services Item -->
            <div class="vf-item tj-hover-3 set-bg inview-animate inview-fadeleft">

                <img src="assets/img/portfolio/horizontal/city3.jpg" alt="alt" class="img-responsive">

                <!-- Item Overlay -->
                <div class="tj-overlay vcenter-wrapper">
                    <div class="overlay-texts vcenter">
                        <h3 class="title">Empty</h3>
                        <h4 class="subtitle">0 %</h4>
                        <br/>
                        <a href="startjourney.html#" class="btn btn-toranj alt">Start Journey</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /Item Overlay -->

            </div>
            <!-- /services Item -->

        </div>
        <!-- /services wrapper -->
    </div>
    <!--/Page main content-->

</div>
```

The problem is that only the stuff from "page-side" is visible, everything else is invisible as you can see in the screenshot below:

[image]

As far as I can see the code also gets loaded correctly, does a Javascript Plugin cause that? How do I correctly load the code?

I hope someone can help me. 
Greetz,

Comment: Is startjourney2.html displayed correctly via direct access ?

Comment: Yes. When I manually put the code into the div it works.

Comment: @SalmanA The Inspector shows me the code of the journey2.html in the main div.

Comment: Invisible or just black text on black background?

Comment: Invisible. When I try to change the font color in the inspector I can not see it.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddler after that load the startjourney2.html?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not. There are many files being used and I never used jsFiddler before, so I don't know how to use them all.

Comment: It seems that all Javascript do not work after clicking the button. Do they get disabled?

Comment: I think it's going to be pretty hard to figure out what the problem is here without a working example.  My best guess is the use of `class="abs dark-template"`, but I'm not sure what it means.

Comment: I hope this can help you. A working version without any ajax: http://jsfiddle.net/ap876mrh/